# How to run a Function after all conditions are met

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

I am trying to make a Contact form with Radio Buttons and Checkboxes for Packages I intend to offer. The first Radio is for the full Package. The Second Radio Button reveals the Checkboxes that breaks the full package into single options.

What I am trying to achieve is when all checkboxes get checked, the first radio gets checked and all checkboxes get unchecked and are hidden. I managed to get the function to work with one little

```
var radio1 = document.getElementbyID('radio1');
var radio2 = document.getElementbyID('radio2');
var checkgroup = document.getElementbyID('checkgroup');
var check1 = document.getElementbyID('check1');
var check2 = document.getElementbyID('check2');
var check3 = document.getElementbyID('check3');
var check4 = document.getElementbyID('check4');
$(document).change(function () {
    if (radio2.checked) {
        checkgroup.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        checkgroup.style.display = "none";
    }
});
$(document).change(function () {
    if ((check1&&check2&&check3&&check4).checked) {
    check1.checked = false;
    check2.checked = false;
    check3.checked = false;
    check4.checked = false;
    checkgroup.style.display = "none";
    radio1.checked = true;
    }
});
```

Whenever I check the the checkbox that is last in the `if()` condition (only the last, not the others) it executes the function which misses the point.
My Goal:
If all get Checked, Execute the Function (Uncheck all, Hide the Checkboxes, Switch back to Radio1). If any 3 get checked nothing should happen.
I feel like i'm missing something, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if ((check1&&check2&&check3&&check4).checked)`
to `if (check1.checked && check2.checked && check3.checked && check4.checked)`

I'm confused that it even worked somewhat since you essentially used && between Javascript objects and not (boolean) variables

Comment: This worked. Another Headache less. Now to implementing this into php for the Contact form

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/h95y86gt/22/

Also, I hope `getElementbyID` is a typo for `document.getElementById()`

Comment: oh yeah thats a typo. I just quickly typed out an example of the original code. Textastic autocompletes values like that for me. I'm afraid your JSFiddle doesn't fix my problem.